# Add custom colorbar to a group of figures

Tags: r, ggplot2

I was given a pretty weird set of csv files from which I was asked to make a network figure. I created each plot with ggplot2 in a for loop and then used ggarrange to merge all plots in a single figure. I would like to have one colorbar either at the bottom or on the right of the figure. The colorbar will have custom limits and will be grayscale. What I tried to do so far but failed:

1. Use an option in ggarrange to make the colorbar but this is only possible if the colorbar was a legend of each individual plot.
2. Create a new row in the figure where I plot only a colorbar at the central part of the figure.

What can be done? As you can see towards the end of the script I created a colorbar. So this verison of the script creates a pdf of two pages. The 1st page has a big colorbar and the 2nd page has the networks. What I have to figure out right now is how to put the colorbar in the same page as the networks and make it smaller. Screenshots: [colorbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNd5y.jpg) [networks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8uLB.jpg)

This is my code:

```
#### Housekeeping ####
rm(list=ls())
graphics.off()
pdf("MI_networks.pdf")
files <- list.files(pattern = ".csv")
files <- files[c(1:6,13:18,25:30)]
library(ggplot2)
library(colourvalues)
library(ggsci)
library(ggpubr)
library(s2dverification)
#### Making Circle Coordinates ####
index <- 0
angle = 360/7
theta <- matrix(nrow=1,ncol=7)
for (i in seq(1,7)){
    theta[i] <- angle + angle*index
    index <- index + 1;
}
x <- 8 + 4*cos(theta*pi/180); # convert degrees to radians
y <- 4 + 4*sin(theta*pi/180);
#### Finding Color Scale ####
all_values <- vector()
for (i in files){
    data <- read.csv(i)
    all_values <- c(all_values,data[,2])
}
connections_colors <- colour_values(all_values,"greys")
#### Making Network ####
plot_list <- list()
for (i in files){
    data <- read.csv(i)
    panel_A <- data.frame(matrix(ncol=4,nrow=16))
    names(panel_A)[1] <- "Name"
    names(panel_A)[2] <- "X"
    names(panel_A)[3] <- "Y"
    panel_A$Name[1] <- "Breathing Rate"
    panel_A$Name[2] <- "Heart Rate" 
    panel_A$Name[3] <- "TCD Left" 
    panel_A$Name[4] <- "TCD Right" 
    panel_A$Name[5] <- "ACM Left" 
    panel_A$Name[6] <- "MIX Left" 
    panel_A$Name[7] <- "ACA" 
    panel_A$Name[8] <- "ACM Right" 
    panel_A$Name[9] <- "MIX Right" 
    panel_A$Name[10] <- "TCD Left" 
    panel_A$Name[11] <- "TCD Right" 
    panel_A$Name[12] <- "ACM Left" 
    panel_A$Name[13] <- "MIX Left" 
    panel_A$Name[14] <- "ACA" 
    panel_A$Name[15] <- "MIX Right" 
    panel_A$Name[16] <- "ACM Right" 
    panel_A$X[1] <- 0
    panel_A$X[2] <- 4
    panel_A$X[3:9] <- 2
    panel_A$X[10:16] <- x
    panel_A$Y[1] <- 8
    panel_A$Y[2] <- 8
    panel_A$Y[3] <- 7
    panel_A$Y[4] <- 6
    panel_A$Y[5] <- 5
    panel_A$Y[6] <- 4
    panel_A$Y[7] <- 3
    panel_A$Y[8] <- 2
    panel_A$Y[9] <- 1
    panel_A$Y[10:16] <- y
    values <- data[,2]
    g <- ggplot(panel_A,aes(x = X, y = Y, color = Name)) + theme(legend.position = "none") + scale_color_jco()
    counter <- 1
    for (point in seq(from = 2, to = 9)){
        index <- which(values[counter] == all_values)[1]
        g <- g + geom_segment(aes(x = panel_A$X[1],y = panel_A$Y[1]), xend = panel_A$X[point],yend = panel_A$Y[point], color = connections_colors[index],lwd = 0.5)
        counter <- counter + 1
    }
    for (point in seq(from = 3, to = 9)){
        index <- which(values[counter] == all_values)[1]
        g <- g + geom_segment(aes(x = panel_A$X[2],y = panel_A$Y[2]), xend = panel_A$X[point],yend = panel_A$Y[point],color = connections_colors[index],lwd = 0.5)
        counter <- counter + 1
    }
    for (point in seq(from = 11, to = 16)){
        index <- which(values[counter] == all_values)[1]
        g <- g + geom_segment(aes(x = panel_A$X[10],y = panel_A$Y[10]), xend = panel_A$X[point],yend = panel_A$Y[point],color = connections_colors[index],lwd = 0.5)
        counter <- counter + 1
    }
    for (point in seq(from = 12, to = 16)){
        index <- which(values[counter] == all_values)[1]
        g <- g + geom_segment(aes(x = panel_A$X[11],y = panel_A$Y[11]), xend = panel_A$X[point],yend = panel_A$Y[point],color = connections_colors[index],lwd = 0.5)
        counter <- counter + 1
    }
    for (point in seq(from = 13, to = 16)){
        index <- which(values[counter] == all_values)[1]
        g <- g + geom_segment(aes(x = panel_A$X[12],y = panel_A$Y[12]), xend = panel_A$X[point],yend = panel_A$Y[point],color = connections_colors[index],lwd = 0.5)
        counter <- counter + 1
    }
    for (point in seq(from = 14, to = 16)){
        index <- which(values[counter] == all_values)[1]
        g <- g + geom_segment(aes(x = panel_A$X[13],y = panel_A$Y[13]), xend = panel_A$X[point],yend = panel_A$Y[point],color = connections_colors[index],lwd = 0.5)
        counter <- counter + 1
    }
    for (point in seq(from = 15, to = 16)){
        index <- which(values[counter] == all_values)[1]
        g <- g + geom_segment(aes(x = panel_A$X[14],y = panel_A$Y[14]), xend = panel_A$X[point],yend = panel_A$Y[point],color = connections_colors[index],lwd = 0.5)
        counter <- counter + 1
    }
    for (point in 16){
        index <- which(values[counter] == all_values)[1]
        g <- g + geom_segment(aes(x = panel_A$X[15],y = panel_A$Y[15]), xend = panel_A$X[point],yend = panel_A$Y[point],color = connections_colors[index], lwd = 0.5)        
        counter <- counter + 1
    }
    if (i == files[1]){
        g <- g + labs(y = "Rest", title = "0.01-0.1 Hz",x="") + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
    }
    else if (i == files[7]){
        g <- g + labs(y = "Sitdown",x="")
    }
    else if (i == files[13]){
        g <- g + labs(y = "Standup",x="")
    }
    else if (i == files[2]){
        g <- g + labs(title = "0.02-0.06 Hz",y="",x="") + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
    }
    else if ( i == files[3]){
        g <- g + labs(title = "0.06-0.15 Hz",y="",x="") + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
    }
    else if ( i == files[4]){
        g <- g + labs(title = "0.15-0.4 Hz",y="",x="") + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
    }
    else if ( i == files[5]){
        g <- g + labs(title = "0.4-1.5 Hz",y="",x="") + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
    }
    else if ( i == files[6]){
        g <- g + labs(title = "< 0.4 Hz",y="",x="") + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
    }
    else{
        g <- g + labs(title="",y="",x="")
    }
    g <- g + geom_point(size = 3,shape = 16) + theme_classic() + theme(line = element_blank(),axis.text.x = element_blank(),axis.text.y = element_blank(),
                                                                       axis.ticks = element_blank()) 
    g <- g + theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 7)) + xlim(min(panel_A$X)-1,max(panel_A$X)+1)
    plot_list <- c(plot_list,list(assign(i,g)))
}
#### Colorbar ####
maximum <- max(all_values)
minimum <- min(all_values)
all_values <- sort(all_values)
lims <- seq(minimum, maximum, (maximum-minimum)/length(all_values))
connections_colors <- colour_values(all_values,"greys")
ColorBar(lims,connections_colors,plot = TRUE,subsampleg = length(all_values),tick_scale = 0,vertical = FALSE,label_digits = 2)
#### Putting all together ####
ggarrange(plotlist = plot_list,ncol = 6, nrow = 3,legend = "bottom", common.legend = TRUE)
dev.off()
```

P.S. I know that the whole script is quite unorthodox but the data I was given are badly shaped.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SO. You can maximize your chance of getting an answer by making it easier for people to read, understand, and try what you have done. Pointing people at your code solely won't work most of the time, since it does not show effort in creating the question.

Comment: Hi OP.  Is it possible instead to share your code without pastebin?  Otherwise, you can share a representative example using a built-in dataset

Comment: You are right, I added the code here with a couple of screenshots.